# How does ordination confer priestly powers to Catholic priests?

Tags: catholicism, priesthood

When a Catholic priest is ordained, from whom and how do they get the powers to do things that only a priest can do (for example, confect the Eucharist, hear Confessions, give the Anointing of the Sick, and, in some cases, give Confirmation)?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). As it is now, it's not entirely clear what you're asking. It appears that you have something specific in mind and that you've tried to ask this question before. But we know only what you have written here. I would suggest spelling your exact question out more clearly. For some tips, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: By “powers” do you mean the capacity to do things that only a priest can do (for example, confect the Eucharist, hear Confessions, give the Anointing of the Sick, and, in some cases, give Confirmation)? If so, I suggest that you specify this in the question.

Comment: I think this could be reopened.

Comment: By the authority of whom , or what , does a Catholic Priest get granted the capacity to do things that only Priests can do , for example, confect the Eucharist, hear Confessions, give the Anointing of the Sick, and, in some cases, give Confirmation ? .

Comment: By "power" do you mean *faculty*?  [CCC 1536 to 1600](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P4R.HTM)would be a good place to start to get an idea of the sacrament of Holy Orders in the Catholic Church.  Once you have read through that perhaps you can refine your question.

Answer (score 2):

For things that are simply a matter of permission, the priest gets his authority from the church. The bishop who performs the ordination confers the authority in the name ofcthe church.

For more spiritual activities, like the ability to perform mass, the power comes from God, mediated through the church.

Comment: Would you care to source this answer with some references to the teachings on the [Sacrament from the Catechism, CCC 1536 to 1600](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P4R.HTM)?